# How to concat VOB files with ffmpeg using stream mapping?

Tags: ffmpeg, dvd, mpeg, vob, mpeg2

I have 5 VOB files, I would like to concat them to a big mpegts file, and keeping only the video stream and the last (3rd) audio stream. Unfortunately the stream ordering is different in the VOBs:

```
    Input #0, mpeg, from 'VTS_01_1.VOB':
      Duration: 00:25:03.00, start: 0.280633, bitrate: 5715 kb/s
        Stream #0:0[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
        Stream #0:1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], max. 7500 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
        Stream #0:2[0x20]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
        Stream #0:3[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
        Stream #0:4[0x81]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
        Stream #0:5[0x82]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    [mpeg2video @ 0x82d3600] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
        Last message repeated 5 times

Input #1, mpeg, from 'VTS_01_2.VOB':
      Duration: 00:24:51.03, start: 1503.128633, bitrate: 5761 kb/s
        Stream #1:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], max. 7500 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
        Stream #1:1[0x21]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
        Stream #1:2[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
        Stream #1:3[0x81]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
        Stream #1:4[0x82]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
        Stream #1:5[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
        Stream #1:6[0x20]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
    [mpeg2video @ 0x86aff00] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
        Last message repeated 8 times

Input #2, mpeg, from 'VTS_01_3.VOB':
      Duration: 00:24:17.94, start: 2993.976633, bitrate: 5891 kb/s
        Stream #2:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], max. 7500 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
        Stream #2:1[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
        Stream #2:2[0x81]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
        Stream #2:3[0x82]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
        Stream #2:4[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
        Stream #2:5[0x20]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
        Stream #2:6[0x21]: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
    [mpeg2video @ 0x868fc20] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
        Last message repeated 8 times

Input #3, mpeg, from 'VTS_01_4.VOB':
      Duration: 00:24:38.52, start: 4451.800633, bitrate: 5809 kb/s
        Stream #3:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], max. 7500 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
        Stream #3:1[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
        Stream #3:2[0x81]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
        Stream #3:3[0x82]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
        Stream #3:4[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
    [mpeg2video @ 0x83a4aa0] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
        Last message repeated 9 times

Input #4, mpeg, from 'VTS_01_5.VOB':
      Duration: 00:02:45.18, start: 5930.104633, bitrate: 5897 kb/s
        Stream #4:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], max. 7500 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
        Stream #4:1[0x80]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
        Stream #4:2[0x81]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
        Stream #4:3[0x82]: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
        Stream #4:4[0x1bf]: Data: dvd_nav_packet
```

So I tried this command:

```
ffmpeg -y f concat -i list.txt -map 0:v -map 0:a:2 -map 1:v -map 1:a:2 -map 2:v -map 2:a:2 -map 3:v -map 3:a:2 -map 4:v -map 4:a:2 -c copy -f mpegts joined.mpeg
```

Where list.txt contains

```
file VTS_01_1.VOB
file VTS_01_2.VOB
file VTS_01_3.VOB
file VTS_01_4.VOB
file VTS_01_5.VOB
```

Unfortunately doesn't work, complete output:

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -i list.txt -map 0:v -map 0:a:2 -map 1:v -map 1:a:2 -map 2:v -map 2:a:2 -map 3:v -map 3:a:2 -map 4:v -map 4:a:2 -c copy -f mpegts joined.mpeg
ffmpeg version 2.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 31 2014 14:53:16 with gcc 4.9.1 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --enable-avisynth --enable-avresample --enable-decoder=atrac3 --enable-decoder=atrac3p --enable-dxva2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-pic --enable-postproc --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-shared --enable-swresample --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      52. 92.100 / 52. 92.100
  libavcodec     55. 69.100 / 55. 69.100
  libavformat    55. 48.100 / 55. 48.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
  libavfilter     4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libavresample   1.  3.  0 /  1.  3.  0
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[concat @ 0x893b1c0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, concat, from 'list.txt':
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 573 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Data: dvd_nav_packet
    Stream #0:1: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], max. 7500 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:2: Subtitle: dvd_subtitle
    Stream #0:3: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:4: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:5: Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
Invalid input file index: 1.
```

How can I achieve the concatenation with stream mapping applied?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "doesn't work"? What does the `ffmpeg` console output show?

Comment: The error message: `Invalid input file index: 1`

Comment: Please provide the complete `ffmpeg` console output.

Comment: Okay, I added it.

Comment: Is there a way for you to break down the steps? First step is to copy only the stream you want to another VOB? Then convert those single VOBs to your eventual output format?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `cat` command from the shell to concatenate the `.vob` files into one.

Here is an example:

To concatenate `file1.vob`, `file2.vob` and `file3.vob` from within the same directory into `Allfiles.vob` you can use the following command:

```
cat file*.vob > Allfiles.vob
```